# Reshaping a Matrix

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

So i have a matrix like

Matrix = $\begin{pmatrix}
Mat1 & Mat2 \\
 Mat 3 & Mat4
\end{pmatrix}
$

Where each matrix mat is a 2x2 matrix

mat1= $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
 3 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
$                     Mat2 = $\begin{pmatrix}
5 & 6 \\
 7 & 8
\end{pmatrix}
$                       Mat3 = $\begin{pmatrix}
9 & 10 \\
 11 & 12
\end{pmatrix}
$                        Mat4 = $\begin{pmatrix}
13 & 14 \\
 15 & 16
\end{pmatrix}
$

How can I reshape this so I have a 4x4 matrix? Where the four terms in the first line are composed by the first line of mat1 and mat2 [1,2,5,6], the second line is composed by the second line of mat1 and mat2 [3,4,7,8], and so on. Basically, it will be exactly the same, except is a 4x4 matrix. I have tried using ArrayReshap[matrix,{4,4}] but it doesn't work because it will take all elements of each matrix to form the line... like the first line would be [1,2,3,4], what i don't want. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ArrayFlatten[matrix]`.